# beforeEach does not run in modular QUnit/Sinon tests with Require.js in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, requirejs, qunit, sinon

Trying to structure QUnit 0.9.0 tests with require.js as explained by [Nathan Davison here](https://nathandavison.com/article/17/using-qunit-and-requirejs-to-build-modular-unit-tests), but using QUnit.module in addition. (coffeescript files are converted to js files before opening test page)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/qunit.css">
    <script data-main="unittestsmain" async src="js/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="qunit"></div>
    <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

unittestsmain.coffee (there were 3 test modules, removed to save space):

```
requirejs.config
  baseUrl: '.'
  paths:
    "sinon": 'js/sinon-1.17.3'
    "QUnit": 'js/qunit'
  shim:
    "QUnit":
      exports: 'QUnit',
      init: () ->
        QUnit.config.autoload = false
        QUnit.config.autostart = false

require ["QUnit", "sinon", "test_sum"],
  (QUnit, sinon, test_sum) ->
    test_sum.run()
    QUnit.load()
    QUnit.start()
```

test_sum.coffee (analogous to one of the examples in [QUnit documentation](https://api.qunitjs.com/QUnit.module/), except for being wrapped into define):

```
define ["sum"], (sum) ->
  run: () ->
    module "Sum class",
      beforeEach: ->
        console.log "in beforeEach:", (p for p of @)
        @adder = sum.Sum()

    test "Sum: common cases", (assert) ->
      assert.equal sum.sum_of_entries([1, 2, 3]), 6
      assert.equal sum.sum_of_entries([]), 0
      return
    # ...
    test "Sum: adder class", (assert) ->
      console.log "in test:", (p for p of @)

      @adder.add(5)
      assert.equal @adder.result(), 0
    return
```

I had no problems before adding the test for adder class, which complains in Firefox:  `this.adder is undefined` (and points to the `test "Sum: adder class"` ... part.). In Chromium: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined", in the same function.

Test page in a browser looks good except for the failing test mentioned above.

The console.log outputs: `in test: ["setup", "teardown", "beforeEach"]` (and no sight of "in beforeEach" in the log.)

Tried some minor variations like => instead of -> , .start, .load order, but it does not help. `define ["QUnit", "sum"], (QUnit, sum) ->` and then using `QUnit.` in test_sum does not help either.

I think, the biggest question is why beforeEach does not run? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The `beforeEach` is from QUnit 2.x, while in QUnit 0.9 it's `setup`.

These matters became clear after reading [QUnit 2.x Upgrade Guide](http://qunitjs.com/upgrade-guide-2.x/).